# Ember: bootstrap classes not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

When I make two components in ember; menu-auth-login and menu-auth-register and I add them using `{{#make-auth-login}}{{/make-auth-login}}` the styling is incorrect somehow.

Can this be due to the Ember views in between? `<div id="ember36" class="ember-view"></div>` contains my components.
Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default an ember component will be in a div tag. You can change that by defining the tagName property inside of the component. Read more about it  [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/).

If you want your component not to be backed by any tag at all, you can specify the tagName property as an empty string.

Comment: That works! Now, I want to attach an event to the element, but I receive this error:

`Error: Assertion Failed: You can not define a function that handles DOM events in the '<cookery@component:menu-auth-login::ember388>' tagless component since it doesn't have any DOM element.`

Comment: Well, its exactly as the error says, you can't use this on components without tagName property. I could probably help more, if you provide the .hbs source code of your component.